# I have been trying to merge 2 data frames on timestamp to the nearest timestamp by pd.merge_asof(), but duplicated merges | python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am merging df1 (1000+ rows)and df2(8 rows) on timestamp via pd.merge_asof()
I want only one nearest merge for each row on df2, and also in a window of 5minutes (plus or minus).

Below is the code I am at:

```
merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='time', direction='nearest',tolerance=pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
```

I am getting multiple merges of df2 on df1.

If there is any other better way to do this, that is welcome as well.
I tried to understand and do with the merge_asof() function documentation and still of no use.

Comment: would you be able to give a small sample input, and a sample output? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) is a **left** merge, thus you should use `df2` on the left side:

```
merged_df = pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on='time', direction='nearest',tolerance=pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
```